# appsettings.json (both dev and prod) ignored by ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, json, https, asp.net-core, appsettings

I would like to setup HTTPS for my ASP.NET core application as well as defining different ports on which my app can listen to (e.g. a bit like what was shown by Scot Hanselman a while ago: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8048).

I have checked the official resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/https

I thought that the default builder was supposed to dig in the appsettings.json (or the appsettings.Development.json when it is relevant).

**Program.cs** content:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        return builder.UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
    }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json** content:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Localhost": {
        "Address": "127.0.0.1",
        "Port": "5001"
      }
    }
  },
  "LocalhostwithHttps": {
    "Address": "127.0.0.1",
    "Port": "44333",
    "Certificate": {
      "Source": "Store",
      "StoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "Subject": "CN=localhost"
    }
  }
}
```

Alas, when starting debugging against the development environment, my web app is ending up starting like this:

```
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: c:\Users\ehoua\Desktop\There
Launching browser (cmd.exe /C start http://localhost:5000)
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Do I have to really give up on the default builder and specify either the appsettings on which the the app needs to rely on or to hardcode the port values...?

[EDIT]
Following @Set answer, I tried the following in `Program.cs`:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    var developmentConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", optional: false)
    .Build();

    var productionConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .Build();

    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseEnvironment("Development").UseConfiguration(developmentConfiguration)
    .UseEnvironment("Production").UseConfiguration(productionConfiguration)
    .UseStartup<Startup>().Build();
}
```

I purposely set the optional argument to false in order to double check whether the appsettings file was properly added to the configuration. Also checked that the environment in the Startup `Configure` method was either Development or Production but still ending up with the same old port 5000 which belongs to none of my appsettings files.

[Edit]
Possible in .NET 2.1

See: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1290#issuecomment-353416087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to call `UseConfiguration` directly to set an URL address read from `appsettings.json`:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", optional: true)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

`CreateDefaultBuilder` method implementation uses `ConfigureAppConfiguration` method internally, not `UseConfiguration`. And there is a difference (from related [Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1148)):

> The `ConfigureAppConfiguration` was intended to configure the `IConfiguration` in the application services whereas `UseConfiguration` is intended to configure the settings of the `WebHostBuilder`. Since the url address is a setting on the `WebHostBuilder` only `UseConfiguration` will work here.
>
> Note that the WebHostBuilder's configuration is added to the application's configuration but the converse is not true; configuring the application's configuration does not affect the WebHostBuilder's configuration.

---

Instread of "Kestel.Endpoints" section your `appsetting.json` should simply have the following:

```
{
   ...
   "urls": "http://127.0.0.1:5001"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this out, I thought it would be less hardcoded and have more conventions about the appsettings files.

Comment: Sadly it didn't work out (I edited my original post with a bit more details), seems a bit weird though cause the configuration seems to be okay with the file but then it's like nothing happened =/

Comment: @Ehouarn modfiy your config file to have  "urls" section. I have updated answer

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1851 according to this link and other issues on Github it seems that the document is not up to date, a workaround is suggested in this thread.